# Import Spring XML context file in Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When using Spring XML beans file, we use below XML element to import another context file.

```
 <import resource="config/scheduler.xml"/>
```

When using Java Config

```
   @Configuration
   @Import({ SchedulerConfig.class })
   public class AppConfig {

   }
```

Can we import another XML context file when using Java Config? Based on above code, it can only import another java config and does not seems to import XML.

The reason I am asking is that a lot of time, we are dependent on other services which only have XML based spring context file. So our implementation becomes limited to XML based config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@ImportResource` instead:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/config/spring.xml")
public class AppConfig {

}
```